# Как сравнить два значения в словаре которые находятся в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется решение задачи по сравнению списка со словарями. Если хотя бы какое-то значение отличается, то все это дело записывается в новый список.
lst1 и lst2 списки со словарями с данными.
в lst3 добавляет значения с двух предыдущих если данные разнятся в lst1 и lst2

```
lst1 = [{'company_name': 'Djonna', 'id_company': '55663', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
        {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '8'},
        {'company_name': "Сберб", 'id_company': '32387', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '240'}]

lst2 = [{'company_name': 'Djonna', 'id_company': '55663', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
        {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
        {'company_name': "Сберб", 'id_company': '32387', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '240'}]
lst3 = [company for company in lst1 if company not in lst2]
```

Пытаюсь по аналогии с предыдущим сравнить значения в списках, но не до конца понимаю как это реализовать.
Если count_review в lst1 > чем count_review в lst2
Может вы сталкивались с подобной задачей.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: если скажем в lst1 company.values()[3] больше чем в lst2 company.values()[3] записать этот словарь в list3. то есть в lst3 записывается {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '8'}, либо в другую сторону записывается {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'}, но те словари, которые одинаковые пропускаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
lst1 = [
    {'company_name': 'Djonna', 'id_company': '55663', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
    {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '8'},
    {'company_name': "Сберб", 'id_company': '32387', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '240'}
]

lst2 = [
    {'company_name': 'Djonna', 'id_company': '55663', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
    {'company_name': 'Vbss', 'id_company': '663388', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '5'},
    {'company_name': "Сберб", 'id_company': '32387', 'city': 'Москва', 'count_review': '240'}
]

lst3 = []
for el1, el2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if int(el1['count_review']) > int(el2['count_review']):
        lst3.append(el1)

print(lst3)
```

Comment: прекрасно! это работает как нужно!